# Literature references for modeling current and future energy costs of floating-point operations and data transfers

Tags: performance, architecture, exascale

I am searching for the most important literature and slide references for modeling current and future energy costs of floating-point operations and data transfers across the CPU, memory, network, and storage.  I have marked this question as a community wiki, and I would prefer that you limit each answer to the following format:

Title, Authors, Location/Conference/Journal, Year, DOI/URL, Summary of what information the paper or presentation provides relevant to my request.

Comment: I remember seeing some papers about this at the SC (Supercomputing) conference.  Have you tried looking there?

Answer (score 1):

There have been numerous panels and reports about exascale computing that should have these sorts of numbers. I would look for reports that came out from DoE (or were written for DoE). Also, there may be relevant stuff at http://www.exascale.org .

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information online that search engines are capable of finding.  Here's three hits to get the ball rolling:

- http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TC.2010.121
- http://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/45737/GT-CSE-2012-01.pdf
- http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2425676.2425691

Comment: Thanks for the Vuduc link, that looks spot on.  Can you help me a little with the last one?  The redirection fails for me.

Comment: I fixed the link.  I do not know why ACM broke it.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE MICRO 2011 paper "[GPUs and the future of parallel computing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6045685&tag=1)" shows that state-of-the-art CPUs and GPUs incur ~1700pJ and ~225pJ, respectively, for each floating-point operation.

For data storage/access cost in different memories (e.g. SRAM, PCM, eDRAM), one has to use tools like [CACTI](http://hplabs.hp.com/people/naveen_muralimanohar/micro07.pdf) and [DESTINY](https://www.academia.edu/9741921/Exploring_Design_Space_of_3D_NVM_and_eDRAM_Caches_Using_DESTINY_Tool) (I am co-developer of DESTINY). Also, [McPAT](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5375438) tool can be used for modeling energy consumption of entire processor, while [DRAMSim2](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5732229) is for memory alone. What you may be looking, may be achieved through combination or modification of these (they are open-source). There are many others, but from these, you can find connected references through Google scholar.